# Clients cannot connect to Windows 10 Mobile Hotspot: How to completely reset configuration?

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, mobile-hotspot

Windows 10 Mobile hotspot studdenly stopped working: I can enable it but clients cannot connect any more: They do not net an IP address assigned. On the other hand, no connected devices show up in "Devices connected" (although the Wifi connection is established).

I tried everything I could:

- Reset Windows Firewall
- Disabled firewall completely
- Deleted `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WlanSvc\Parameters\HostedNetworkSettings`
- Various restarts
- Removing my Wifi driver from the device manager
- Removing Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter and Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter from the device manager
- Uncountable times (I guess hundreds) properties of my Wifi connection, Sharing, "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection" enabled/disabled
- Troubleshooter for Windows network
- **Update**: Deinstalled everything that creates network interfaces (VirtualBox and OpenVPN) and reset network configuration

How can this Hotspot get working again?

PS: I am able to assign a static IP to the "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter" and to a connected device (iPhone). They can ping each other.

Comment: You have been changing the adapters installed, did you remove the Microsoft miniport adapter or change something in it?

Comment: "Microsoft miniport", you mean "WAN Miniport" adapters? I have not touched those. However, I created a hosted network (and removed it again).

Comment: Lets start with updating the microsoft miniport driver:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1ijaq7nff7dpmc/SuperUser.HotspotNotWorking.ScanForHardwareChanges.png?dl=0

And then the scond thing to do: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6cphn6kddnthwli/SuperUser.HotspotNotWorking.ScanForHardwareChanges.2.png?dl=0